# Create a browser only session (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, users, session

I was recently in a Virgin media shop and was interested to see that they had laptops running Ubuntu for customers to browse the web on. The setup itself was interesting and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to recreate it.  The features were:

Only running Firefox, no other panels or menus

I tried running a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) but it gave a message saying the user didn't have permission to access the x server (or something similar)

I realise to recreate this is a function of controlling both user privileges and session parameters but I'm not sure how I would go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: The search keyword you want is 'kiosk'.  When I google 'Ubuntu kiosk' I get some useful-looking results.

Comment: Please don't cross-post between SE sites: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270357/how-to-create-a-web-browser-only-session

Comment: This is called Kiosk mode, and this question will be quickly answered in [ubuntu.se] if it's not already there.

Comment: @maggotbrain: Please look up the meaning of the term *crosspost* before you throw it around again, because the link you provided is not that, and if that's your evidence, *this was not cross posted*.

Comment: @goldilocks Er. [How is it not?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting) It's the same post by the same user posted at the same time

Comment: @MichaelMrozek : When I click on the link in maggotbrain's comment (and I did just check again), I get an askubuntu question about kiosks from April 2012 by a user *puyo* who does not have a membership here.

Comment: Looks like I in fact get redirected to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk Did not know SE would do that kind of thing, but strange it happens for me and evidently not you or maggotbrain (maybe because I am not an askubuntu member?).  All apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @goldilocks Ah, I didn't realize that happened for duplicates either; it must be a rep thing. You can see the original [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270357/how-to-create-a-web-browser-only-session?noredirect=1)

Comment: My understanding is that unregistered users (like @goldilocks on AU) are auto redirected to the master of a dupe; Hence the confusion.  Also, your comment to maggotbrain sounds rather rude to me...  Just sayin.